# Angular adding an extra slash before query parameter

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created an angular application and while opening it in browser after `ng serve`.
The URL looks like this: `localhost:4200`

I also have a search functionality which takes the query string from url and shows the results.
The url changes from `localhost:4200?qr=dummy` to `localhost:4200/?qr=dummy`

I want to remove that extra slash before **`?qr=dummy`**.

**Actual:** `http://localhost:4200/?qr=dummy`
**Expected:** `http://localhost:4200?qr=dummy`

How can I do that using Location API ?

Comment: Instead of hacking the URL's behaviour, why don't you just handle the standard way it works with `localhost:4200/?qr=dummy`? What's wrong with this syntax?

Comment: Why do you want to remove that slash?

Comment: I have a situation where I am loading the angular components on a different page it is appending a `/` at the end for every url and also the search should look like this: `https://example.com?qr=dummy` without the slash.

Comment: Yes, we got it. Our question is, _why_? Why do you _need_ to remove the slash? Why do you want to hack the way URLs in browsers work? What problem are you trying to solve?